# infinite when dividing by a float which is smaller than 1?

Tags: objective-c, c

i have this code :

```
 float f;
    float time;
    time=samplesPerPeriod/44;
    f=(1/time)*1000;
```

when samplesPerPeriod is 35 i get infinite in this log:

```
NSLog(@"frequency:%f Hz",f);
```

cant i dividing in a number which is smaller then 1 ?
is it have to do with the fact that this is a c function in objective c class ?

thanks .

Comment: Is `samplesPerPeriod` an integer value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use floats for the line

```
time=samplesPerPeriod/44;
```

So instead do

```
time=(float)samplesPerPeriod/44.0;
```

If `samplesPerPeriod` is an `int`, then the division will be integer division. Which means you're really doing

```
35/40
```

which, as an `int`, is `0` which is **then** converted to a `float` with value `0.0`. So you'll need to cast `samplesPerPeriod` to a float before the division, and to be safe and clear, use a `float` value of `44.0` in the denominator as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `samplesPerPeriod` is an integer type.  If so, then `samplesPerPeriod/44` is performed in integer maths, so the result is 0.  You're then doing 1/0.0, which is infinity.

To fix this, do any of the following:

```
time = (float)samplesPerPeriod / 44;
time = samplesPerPeriod / 44.0;
time = (float)samplesPerPeriod / 44.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Which type of var `samplesPerPeriod` is? I think `int`. Your code should be something like this to work properly:

```
time = (float)samplesPerPeriod / 44.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

35/44 results in 0.0 because

```
- in case of = operator right side is evaluated first and assigned to left.
- 35/44 is 0. (as both are int)

so finally 1/0.0 results in infinite.
```

Use `35f / 44f` , then it will be considered as floats

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `samplesPerPeriod` is of an integer type

```
float time;
time = samplesPerPeriod / 44;
```

then both operands of the / operator are of integer type and an integer division is performed.

To perform a floating-point division with `float` operands.
Use either:

```
time = samplesPerPeriod / 44.0f;
```

or

```
time = (float) samplesPerPeriod / 44;
```

Moreover your `time` object is of `float` type. Using 44.0f (a `float` literal) instead of 44.0 (a `double` literal), you are guaranteed that the division is performed with `float` instead of `double` operands. This can be critical for example if your CPU is only able to perform FPU single precision. The use of the `double` literal would force software emulation for the division of operands of `double` type. Note that gcc has an option to warn in such cases:

`-Wdouble-promotion`